# MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT cannot be updated

Tags: mysql

I have the same problem as Justin, 
([Can't change MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367194/cant-change-mysql-auto-increment)) 
ie trying to change the auto_increment value is ignored.

I have used the:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName AUTO_INCREMENT = 123;
```

before and it worked fine. I am also using InnoDB and have a primary key on the column that is set to Auto_increment.

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `PerRef` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Surname` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PerRef`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have added some dummy entries to a table during testing. I have deleted these entries and want to reset the auto_inc value to where it should be.

Surely you don't have to remove the key before being able to reset the Auto_inc value?

What are we missing here?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks @Prasad - I had read that post. What seems to be happening is that I can put the Auto_inc value up but never back down again. The highest value in my table is currently 35. I changed Auto_inc to 40 and all good. Then I tried to put it back to 36 and no go ??

Comment: As I said, I had done some testing and want to return the table to its pretesting state. I don't want gaps in the PerRef numbers.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not permit you to decrease the AUTO_INCREMENT value, as specified here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

> **You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the**
>   **value that is currently in use**. For both InnoDB and MyISAM, if the
>   value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column value plus one.

**MySQL reset auto increment value by using TRUNCATE TABLE statement:**

The TRUNCATE TABLE statement removes all the data of a table and reset auto-increment value to zero. The following illustrates the syntax of the TRUNCATE TABLE statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
```

By using the TRUNCATE TABLE statement, you can only reset the auto-increment value to zero. In addition, all the data in the table is wiped out so you should use the TRUNCATE TABLE statement with extra caution.

**MySQL reset auto increment value using DROP  TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements:**

You can use a pair of statements DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE to reset the auto-increment column. Like the TRUNCATE TABLE statement, those statements removes all the data and reset the auto-increment value to zero.

```
DROP TABLE table_name;
CREATE TABLE table_name(...);
```

Comment: I am not trying to set Auto_increment to a value lower than one that is in use! My highest value is 36. I then set Auto_inc to 40 using ALTER TABLE (highest value is still 36) but I cannot set Auto_inc back to 37 ??

Comment: @DavidG why do you want to do that?? what are you trying to achieve by changing the auto_increment value to 40 and then to 37 when you have the records in your table?? Above its clearly saying that it will not assign a value less than or equal to the current value that it holds. so when you change it to 40 then you cannot decrease the value in auto_increament

Comment: What it says is you can't set it lower than the maximum value in the table - which is 36. I only set it to 40 as a test to see if I could then set it back to 37. The reason I want to do this is after I put say 5 dummy records into the table, then I delete them and want to reset the Auto_inc to where it was so that the next real added record will get a consecutive PerRef number.

Comment: This seems to be an InnoDB thing. When I changed the table to MyISAM I can change the Auto_inc back.  ??